# Make working jar file

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project and I whant to make jar file. 
When i run my jar which i build with onejar-maven-plugin plugin I retrieve this message:

[image]

This is my **pom.xml** :

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>..</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
   ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
        <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

What am i doing wrong? Also i use [this](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/) tutorial

Comment: I recommend Spring Boot if you want to create a runnable jar from a Spring project

Comment: hm..to use spring boot i should rewrite much code. It did not suit me. But if i not right, coud you please show me example of fast spring boot integration?